# Knapsack Decryption Help

Tags: cryptography

I am currently trying to decrypt this superincreasing Knapsack cipher. I thought I understood how to do it, but the answers I am getting don't seem correct.

Superincreasing w: [2, 9, 16, 43, 71, 156, 301, 619]

q: 1337

modular inverse of r: 236

message: 2846 2947 1589 4010 4633 4053 1531 4053 2738 1589 3426 5676 2262 5676 3902 425 425 2947 4842

What I've done is 236(c)mod1337= x where c equals a number in the message.For example, (236)(2846)mod1337, and then I would get 482. Next, I subtracted the largest element in w which was less than or equal to 482, and repeated until the difference was equal to 0.

482-301=181

181-156=25

25-16=9

9-9=0

I then added the differences 181+25+9+0 = 215, converted 215 to binary 11010111, and then to text, x.

When I started calculating the next numbers, I started getting non ASCII characters, leading me to believe I messed up somewhere when calculating the cipher.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ethan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afte you have calculated $482$ you want to find a subset of the set $\{2, 9, 16, 43, 71, 156, 301, 619\}$ such set the elements of this subset sum up to $482$. One such subset is 
$$\{9,16,156,301\}$$
It is the only subset that sums up to $482$.

To find such a subset is equivalent to solve the equation 
$$2 \cdot x_0 +  9 \cdot x_1 +  16 \cdot x_2  +   43 \cdot x_3 +   71 \cdot x_4 +   156 \cdot x_5 +   301 \cdot x_6 +   619  \cdot x_7   = 482$$
such that
$$ x_0\in\{0,1\},\;x_1\in\{0,1\},\;\ldots,x_7\in\{0,1\}$$
The solution is
$$(x_0,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7)=(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0)$$
because you have $x_i=1$ if the coefficient of $x_i$ of the equation is in the subset and $x_i=0$ otherwise.
So the binary message is $01100110$ This represents the binary number

$$ 0 \cdot 2^0+ 1 \cdot 2^1+1 \cdot 2^2+0 \cdot 2^3+0 \cdot 2^4+1 \cdot 2^5+1 \cdot 2^6+0 \cdot 2^7\\=0 \cdot 1+ 1 \cdot 2+1 \cdot 4+0 \cdot 8+0 \cdot 16+1 \cdot 32+1 \cdot 64+0 \cdot 128\\=102$$
This is the ascii code for `f`.

You find the subset by using your algorithm based on the supermonotonicity of the vector but then you have to add up  the corresponding  powers of $2$ and not the differences.

**remark 1**: maybe the $x_i$ are indexed in the other direction, such that
$$2 \cdot x_7 +  9 \cdot x_6 +  16 \cdot x_5  +   43 \cdot x_4 +   71 \cdot x_3 +   156 \cdot x_2 +   301 \cdot x_1 +   619  \cdot x_0   = 482$$

**remark 2**: convince yourself why the supermonotonicity is important

1. it allows you to find the  $x_i$ efficiently
2. it guaranties that the subset is uniquely determined